# unable to select my account in MS Authenticator

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, adal, authenticator

I developed an app that uses the ADAL library with broker support to authenticate.

Since two weeks now I seem to be unable to select my account in MS Authenticator when it opens through the Adal library.

Looks as if updates of MS Authenticator have caused the issue.

I just found one of the old phones which did not have the latest MS Authenticator update of februari 7th, 2020 and found it to work just fine. Then I updated to the latest version 6.2002.0898 and now I can no longer select an account.

Anybody knows about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update of the MS Authenticator app from 19 Februari 2020 on Android has fixed the problem.